# Python's __repr__ method when __init__ takes an array as argument

Tags: python, oop, repr

I am quite new to OOP with Python, and trying to understand how the `__repr__` method should output in this particular instance.

When initialising the Playlist class, an array, containing song objects, can be passed as an argument. You can also pass nothing as an argument, and add songs objects to a playlist using a separate `add_song` method.

However I'm not quite sure how to set up my `__repr__` method in this case. If I pass an array of 10+ song objects, the output of repr method would be extremely large - as each song object itself has several parameters.

Is there a Pythonic way of doing this?

EDIT: To make my question less vague - from what I understand, the repr method is intended to return a string representation of an object. In my case, Playlist objects are passed an array as an argument (or nothing at all). If an array is passed, this contains song objects, which themselves have a number of parameters such as name of song, language of song, etc. My question is whether there is a 'correct' way to set up the repr method in this instance - or if this is really just up to me to decide.

```
class Playlist:
        
        def __init__(self, songs = None):
            if songs is None:
                self.playlist = []
            else:
                self.playlist = songs
                
        def __repr__(self):
            return (f"{self.__class__.__name__}({self.playlist})")
```

Output of printing a playlist object:

> Playlist([Song(Random Song Name 1, English, 50), Song(Random Song Name
> 2, English, 25)])

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you currently see in the output, what do you want the output to be, and how is it different? It appears that you're asking what you should decide on for your output, and that's entirely dependent on your opinion as the person writing the code

Comment: If your songs have ids, you could just print those? However, if you have ids of length 4 digits and a playlist has 100 songs, that's still 400 chars. But an id is probably the shortest unique attribute of a song.

Comment: Python's `list` and `dict` can also have very long string representations. So, that's not the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Its up to you. `repr` should return a string that gives greater typing information than the more human friendly `str`. If size gets in the way, you are free to fix that the way you think is best. For instance, `pandas` gives you an abbreviated view that contains other details such as the full dimension.

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame([list(range(5)) for _ in range(500)])
>>> print(repr(df))
     0  1  2  3  4
0    0  1  2  3  4
1    0  1  2  3  4
2    0  1  2  3  4
3    0  1  2  3  4
4    0  1  2  3  4
..  .. .. .. .. ..
495  0  1  2  3  4
496  0  1  2  3  4
497  0  1  2  3  4
498  0  1  2  3  4
499  0  1  2  3  4

[500 rows x 5 columns]
```

Its okay to do the same thing with songs.

Comment: Thank you! That's a good idea. I'll try playing around with it and see if I can output it slightly neater. I just wasn't sure if there was an official way of doing this.

Comment: No, its all over the place. But you want it to be as unambiguous as possible. Maybe stats on the number of songs, artists, albums? Pandas really should include that fact that its a DataFrame and the types of the columns, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

## `__repr__` in Python

**[Source](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/__str__-vs-__repr#:%7E:text=According%20to%20the%20official%20Python,string%20representations%20of%20an%20object.)**

> According to the official Python documentation, `__repr__` is a built-in function used to compute the “official” string reputation of an object,

`__repr__` should be **return a string representation of your object**. This is useful for debugging. That means you should return all the attributes of a class in a way you would prefer.

### Example

```py
class Entity:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Name: " + self.name
```

From your example, you need to return the names of the songs and their ID's.

```py
def __repr__(self):
    songs = ""
    for i in range(len(playlist)):
        songs+=f"{i+1}. {playlist[i]}"
    return songs
```

This is how **I** would do it. You are free to choose the output format. I am pretty sure you must have more attributes in this class. You shall return them in this function.

### From your question

It is true that if you have a huge list of songs for an object the string representation could be huge. A good way must be to make the string representation more organized and hence easier to read. Something like

```
     Object x
Song 1 : 
   Name: name
   Artist: artist
   Length: length
```

The point of this method is that you can call it whenever you want and get all the attributes of the object, Suppose you have an issue regarding the artist being displayed incorrectly. A good start of debugging can be to display the object attributes in an organized manner so you can trace back to exactly where the problem comes from.

- You could split the songs into the different genres/artist and print
  them separately
- Take it one step further by writing the string into a file so you can
  read everything peacefully. It's all up to you.

Comment: This doesn't really address the question, and it incorrectly implements `__repr__`. `__repr__` shouldn't *print anything at all*

Comment: Yes, I am 100% sure. `__repr__` must return a `str` object. The function's you have above return `None`. `__repr__` isn't in charge of *printing* an object, but as your quote states, "compute the “official” string reputation of an object".

Comment: In any case, your answer doesn't really address the OPs question, which is admittedly vague.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give this a try! I wasn't sure if there was an official way of doing this or not.

Comment: @AaronWright I didn't address your question earlier, but now I have edited my answer hopefully answering your question

Comment: @AryanParekh Hi yes this makes sense. Thank you! I will give this a shot and see what it looks like. Although I'm now wondering if the way I've structured my media library is just flat out incorrect.

Comment: @AaronWright you can post your code on [https://codereview.stackexchange.com/](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get a good review if your code.

Comment: @AryanParekh That's really useful! Thanks. However this is for an assignment so I won't be posting it online, at least not publicly.